# compile error: user-defined type not defined

Tags: vb6

There is compile error 'user-defined type not defined' I get in VB6 when I was tried to compile this code. Can anybody tell me what I need to do to solve this error? Following is the line for which I got the error:

```
Public Conn As ADODB.Connection

Public rs As ADODB.Recordset
```

Comment: Have you included in project a reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['User Defined Type Not Defined' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24261557/user-defined-type-not-defined-error)

Answer (score 12):

You need to add the reference to the ADO type library:

1. Open your project.
2. Click the **Project** menu item, then select **References...**
3. From **Available References**, check the box next to **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects n.n Library**, where n.n is one of the following:

   - 6.1 - if you want your application to run only on Windows 7 or later
   - 2.8 - if you want your application to run on Windows XP or later
4. Click **OK**.

You may also want to look at [Referencing the ADO Libraries In a Visual Basic 6 Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679808%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from the [ADO Programmer's Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).